# Как сделать алерты на redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

У меня есть такой код на react ts, redux toolkit:

```
if (error) {
    console.log("Ошибка")
  }
  else {
    console.log("Успешно")
  }
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы вместо консоль лога я вызывал функцию, которая находится в другом файле, в нее я передавал, например, `visibility={true}` и `type={error (или succes)}`, и таким образом в той функции с помощью редакса менялся глобальный объект `alert` с полями `visibility` и `type`.

Я хочу такую функцию, которую я могу вызвать, например, в `try..catch` или внутри другой функции или хука, максимально переиспользуемую, потому что она будет использоваться во многих местах.

Пробовал ставить вместо консоль лога `useDispatch`, чтобы менять состояние, но оно не хочет так просто работать, ругается, что я хуки вызываю внутри функций, например, или внутри `try..catch`

Помогите пожалуйста, уже не знаю что делать.

Comment: **Функции javaScript** и **Функциональные компоненты React** это разное. useDispatch это хук и должен вызываться только в функциональных компонентах. Определитесь, что именно вы хотите сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, ваша ошибка заключается в том, что функцию, которая обращается к store и меняет глобальный объект alert вы попытались вызвать внутри другой функции с помощью useDispatch. У вас появлется ошибка о том, что нельзя вызывать хуки внутри функциий и это так, хуки необходимо вызывать непременно внутри компонентов, если у вас функция внутри компонента, то useDispatch внутри функции не сработает. Вместо этого вам необходимо приравнять dispatch=useDispatch() в компоненте и в дальнейшем использовать dispatch() внутри функций для того, чтобы вызывать функцию, который будет менять глобальный объект alert. То есть:dispatch(ваша функция которая меняет глобальный объект). Если я где-то ошибся, думаю мне дадут об этом знать.